# Is there any props to change text style(i.e. bold to unbold) in React tooltip?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, web-applications, react-tooltip

Can anyone please explain to me how can we make bold text to unbold in `react-tooltip`. I have used npm react-tooltip

note: default text is bold I want normal text.

Comment: You can achieve this with assigning `font-weight: normal;` to your tooltip class easily.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can customize the text style via the [API of ReactTooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip#options)

```
<ReactTooltip textColor={"lightblue"} backgroundColor={"white"} />
```

---

Or simply use `!important`

```
.Tooltip {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```
<ReactTooltip className="Tooltip" />
```

Which is been suggested in its document demo:

```
.extraClass {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
.extraClass:hover {
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

[image: Edit react-tooltip-example-3.11.6]

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the `font-weight: normal` as mentioned using the data attribute used by react-tooltip.

```
a[data-tip] {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: I believe this only change the style of `Text`, rather than the `Tooltip`